# Nextjs 14+, MUI and Content Security Policy

Tags: next.js, material-ui, content-security-policy

I am trying to get a CSP to work between Nextjs and MUI. I've followed the [Nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/content-security-policy) and the [MUI Docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/content-security-policy/). From the nextjs side I am using a nonce which is generated in my middleware.

**Middleware Code**

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  //create a nonce for CSP
  const nonce = 'YzA5OGFiZDktN2ZjYi00MWRiLTllZTctZGVlYzNkZWMxNmMz';
  
  //declare the csp header const
  const cspHeader = `
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}' 'strict-dynamic';
    style-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}' 'unsafe-inline';
    img-src 'self' blob: data:;
    font-src 'self';
    object-src 'none';
    base-uri 'none;
    form-action 'self';
    frame-ancestors 'none';
    block-all-mixed-content;
    upgrade-insecure-requests;
  `;

  const contentSecurityPolicyHeaderValue = cspHeader
    .replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')
    .trim();

  const res = NextResponse.next();

  //set the CSP header.
  res.headers.set(
    'Content-Security-Policy',
    contentSecurityPolicyHeaderValue
  );
  res.cookies.set('nonce', nonce, { httpOnly: false, secure: true});
```

I am storing the nonce as a cookie and then retrieving this cookie within my RootLayout.tsx and passing this into my themeregistry.tsx.

**Root Layout Code**

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const nonceValue = cookies().get('nonce')?.value || ' '; 
  console.log('cookie nonce in layout root:, ', nonceValue); 


  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className} style={{
        overflow: 'auto'
      }}>
        <ThemeRegistry nonce={nonceValue}>
          <CssBaseline />
          {children}
        </ThemeRegistry>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

**Theme Registry Code**

```
export default function ThemeRegistry({ children, nonce }: { children: React.ReactNode, nonce: string }) {
  console.log('nonce in theme registry: ', nonce);
  
  return (
    <NextAppDirEmotionCacheProvider options={{ key: 'mui', nonce: nonce, prepend: true }}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </NextAppDirEmotionCacheProvider>
  );
}
```

This then gets passed into the Cache and applied to the style.

**Cache Provider**

```
return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {globals.map(({ name, style }) => (
          <style
            key={name}
            data-emotion={`${registry.cache.key}-global ${name}`}
            nonce={nonceValue}
            // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: style }}
          />
        ))}
        {styles && (
          <style
            data-emotion={dataEmotionAttribute}
            nonce={nonceValue}
            // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: styles }}
          />
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  });

  return <CacheProvider value={registry.cache}>{children}</CacheProvider>;
}
```

I have been able to confirm that the nonce is being applied to the DOM across both the style tags and script tags. As an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1705620629952" data-precedence="next_static/css/app/layout.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/app/(authenticated)/organisation/layout.css?v=1705620629952" data-precedence="next_static/css/app/(authenticated)/organisation/layout.css"/>
        <link rel="preload" as="script" fetchPriority="low" nonce="YzA5OGFiZDktN2ZjYi00MWRiLTllZTctZGVlYzNkZWMxNmMz" href="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?v=1705620629952"/>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js?v=1705620629952" async="" nonce="YzA5OGFiZDktN2ZjYi00MWRiLTllZTctZGVlYzNkZWMxNmMz"></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/app-pages-internals.js" async="" nonce="YzA5OGFiZDktN2ZjYi00MWRiLTllZTctZGVlYzNkZWMxNmMz"></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/app/(authenticated)/organisation/layout.js" async="" nonce="YzA5OGFiZDktN2ZjYi00MWRiLTllZTctZGVlYzNkZWMxNmMz"></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/app/layout.js" async="" nonce="YzA5OGFiZDktN2ZjYi00MWRiLTllZTctZGVlYzNkZWMxNmMz"></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/app/(authenticated)/organisation/locations/page.js" async="" nonce="YzA5OGFiZDktN2ZjYi00MWRiLTllZTctZGVlYzNkZWMxNmMz"></script>
        <title>PharmaHub</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Next generation pharmacy software"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" sizes="16x16"/>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js" noModule="" nonce="YzA5OGFiZDktN2ZjYi00MWRiLTllZTctZGVlYzNkZWMxNmMz"></script>
        <style data-emotion="mui-global 13wfo5t" nonce="YzA5OGFiZDktN2ZjYi00MWRiLTllZTctZGVlYzNkZWMxNmMz">
            html {
```

However in scenarios where there is any interactivity such as a button click that opens a drawer or rendering an MUI table / data-grid these won't display. When the csp is not set, everything displays fine.

If I look in my network tab I can see the CSP applying with the nonce value matching the cookie which matches the theme and so on.

I am at a bit of a loss with how to debug further here. I've tried to remove other CSP settings however this will 'break' the css of the app and it might be that MUI is all or nothing?

I am not using the default MUI cache set up for Next but when I try that I get a whole different set of compile errors (outside the scope of this question).

If anyone has any experience setting this up it would be great if you could point me in the right direction!

Thanks